# PHP PDO mySQL return null

Tags: php, pdo

The following code returns me people with similar telephone numbers. It works perfectly but when there are no numbers the function still returns information meaning that I cannot check hide a certain box if there are no other people with similar numbers.

THE FUNCTION

```
function getothers($tid,$criteria,$telephone,$telephone2,$elector){
            global $dbh;
            $tid = '-TID'.$tid;
             $sql = "SELECT * FROM electors WHERE ((telephone > 0 AND telephone IN ('$telephone','$telephone2'))  OR (telephone2 > 0 AND telephone2 IN ('$telephone','$telephone2'))) $criteria AND records NOT RLIKE '$tid' AND ID != '$elector'  LIMIT 10";
            $result = $dbh->query($sql);
            return $result;
        }
```

THE CALL

```
<?php $others = getothers($post['TID'],$post['criteria'],$elector['telephone'],$elector['telephone2'],$elector['ID']); ?>
```

THE LINE THAT DOES NOT WORK

```
<?php if(!$others){?>
```

`$others` still has something in it despite no results. I think I might be missing a line in  y PDO. Any ideas?

The print_r

```
PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => SELECT * FROM electors WHERE ((telephone > 0 AND telephone IN ('02085414023 ','')) OR (telephone2 > 0 AND telephone2 IN ('02085414023 ',''))) AND (this_vi_street = '' AND this_vi_telephone = '') AND (mosaic IN ('A01','A02','A03','A04','A05','A07','B11','C15','C16','C17','C18','H46','J52','K57','K58','K60') OR last_vi IN ('C','P')) AND postal_vote != 1 AND records NOT RLIKE '-TID1' AND ID != '13' LIMIT 10 )
```

Comment: If you're using PDO, please use **prepared statements**. You're completely foregoing the advantages of PDO and are just using it like your old mysql_ functions. Please see the examples in the manual.

Comment: Thats probably a good idea. Would you give me just a small hand so I can see it in context of what I am doing. Take my function above. How would it look as a prepared statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe do something like

```
$result = $dbh->query($sql);
if($result->rowCount()>0)
{
return $result;
}

return false;
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments, a version using prepared statements:

```
function getothers($tid, $criteria, $telephone, $telephone2, $elector) {
    global $dbh;

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT *
                             FROM electors
                            WHERE ((telephone > 0 AND telephone IN (:telephone, :telephone2))
                                   OR (telephone2 > 0 AND telephone2 IN (:telephone, :telephone2)))
                                  $criteria
                                  AND records NOT RLIKE :tid
                                  AND ID != :elector
                            LIMIT 10";

    $stmt->execute(array(
        ':telephone'  => $telephone,
        ':telephone2' => $telephone2,
        ':tid'        => '-TID' . $tid,
        ':elector'    => $elector
    ));

    return $stmt->fetchAll();
}
```

There are still some bad points in this code:

- Uses `global` to get the DB connection, this is overall bad application structure. You should probably use a class or pass `$dbh` as a regular argument into the function.
- Concatenates `$criteria` into the prepared statement. Do you really need such dynamic conditions that you can't prepare a query for it without concatenating whole SQL blocks into it?
- Doesn't necessarily address your actual problem of function returns.